# Get Value from Input When Consists Apostrophe Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I retrieve value from database: "Adam's Apple" and put it as name for input. But in Laravel 4.2, I tried:

```
Input::get('Adam\u2019s_Apple') 
Input::get('Adam\'s_Apple')
```

it shows empty value. Why? How to get the value?

Comment: Try a dd(Input::all()); to see what the key is.

Comment: " Adamâ€™s_Apple " what does this means?

Comment: It's how php encoded your key. It can't have special characters

Comment: You should strip special characters from input names.

Comment: But you might be able to use that string to access the value. But it's a hack.